# How do I enable auto code formatting for flake8 in PyCharm

Tags: python, plugins, pycharm, pep8, flake8

I use Tox to run unit tests, with a flake8 command that checks for code formatting errors. Each time I code in PyCharm, I run tox then realise I have a bunch of annoying formatting errors I have to back and manually fix. I would like PyCharm to automatically format the code (according to flake8 google for me each time it auto-saves after I stop typing.

my tox testenv looks like this:

```lsp
[testenv:flake8]
commands=flake8 <my_code_directory>
deps =     
  flake8==2.4.1    
  flake8-import-order==0.11    
  pep8-naming==0.4.1 

[flake8] 
max-line-length = 120 
import-order-style = google
```

Is this possible? Do I have to download a specific plugin somewhere? If not with flake8, what about just PEP-8?

Answer (score 20):

Flake8 and import ordering are not auto-fixable in a way that complies with what you're seeing. You can auto-fix pep8 with autopep8.

There are discussions [here](https://github.com/PyCQA/flake8/issues/545) about implementing this for Flake8 though.

Answer (score 17):

For automatically sorting import statements use [isort](https://github.com/timothycrosley/isort/). Consider using [black](https://pypi.org/project/black/) to auto-format your Python code.

Edit: [ruff](https://github.com/charliermarsh/ruff) can replace flake8 and isort and is also much faster because it's based on Rust. It also supports [LSP](https://github.com/charliermarsh/ruff-lsp), so PyCharm you should be able to use it from within PyCharm.

Answer (score 12):

The tool you want is probably [autopep8](https://pypi.org/project/autopep8/). This is especially because the warning codes it uses correspond to the flake8 ones.

For example, if you want to autofix all instances of E701 multiple statements on a single line warning, run the following

```
for f in `find . -name "*.py"`; do autopep8 --in-place --select=E701 $f; done
```

Comment: find: illegal option -- n

Comment: @OmarS. Interesting. Your find is probably different from my find :P. I use it there to print all `.py` files in current directory and sub-directories. If you find out how to do that on your machine, let me know. Maybe, try `--` instead of `-`?

Comment: @OmarS. try instead `find . -name "*.py"`

Comment: I can't get autopep to actually modify the file. I am trying to address F401: `autopep8 --in-place --select=F401 --aggressive path/to/my/file.py`.

My versions are: autopep8 1.7.0 (pycodestyle: 2.9.1)