# Descriptive flake8 errors in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, static-code-analysis, flake8

`PyCharm` does not have a [built-in support for `flake8` at the moment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41899007/771848). But, `flake8` can be configured to run as an external tool.

Sometimes, especially for Python newcomers, not every `flake8` warning is understandable and additional clarification is required.

We've recently stumbled upon the [`Flake8Rules` project](https://lintlyci.github.io/Flake8Rules/) which attempts to describe every single warning in a detailed way with supportive examples.

Is there a way to combine PyCharm, `flake8` and `Flake8Rules` altogether to have static code analysis warnings displayed with additional descriptions or links to the `Flake8Rules` catalog?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

It is definitely possible.

One approach would be to adjust the `flake8` output using [the `--format` command-line option](http://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/user/options.html#cmdoption-flake8-format) to specify http(s) links to the `Flake8Rules` catalog:

```
--format='%(path)s:%(row)d,%(col)d:%(code)s:%(text)s:https://lintlyci.github.io/Flake8Rules/rules/%(code)s.html'
```

The problem then is for the console or PyCharm output window to render the links properly.

Fortunately, we can do that using the plugins - ["Awesome Console"](https://github.com/anthraxx/intellij-awesome-console) for the terminal and ["Console Link"](https://github.com/siosio/consoleLink) for the output window.

---

### Step-by-step Instructions

1. make sure to have `flake8` installed in the current Python environment
2. install "Awesome Console" plugin:

- go to `PyCharm Preferences -> Plugins -> Browser Repositories...`
- find "Awesome Console" and install (PyCharm restart required):
  [image]

3. configure "flake8" as an [External Tool](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/external-tools.html):

- go to `PyCharm Preferences -> Tools -> External Tools -> "+"`
- configure the path to `flake8` as well as `$FilePath$` placeholder for the desired directory/path to be processed:
  [image]

---

### Demo

Now, let's say we have created this `test.py` file with a few violations:

```
def f(a = 10):
  return a*10
```

If we right-click on a `test.py` file, select `External Tools -> flake8`, this is the output we are going to get (note the clickable links for every warning):

[image]

Now, whenever in doubt, we can follow the link for additional details about a warning.

This is just one way to do it, would be happy to hear if there is an easier or better way to combine these tools and projects.

Comment: `Awesome console` is just AWESOME <3

Comment: I think it's `$FilePath$` instead of `$FileDir$/$FileName$`.

Comment: I tried to use this for Windows and a conda environment today got this error: Error running 'flake8'
Cannot run program
"C:\Users\Steve\anaconda3\envs\lmageProcessing\Lib\site-packages\flake8\__main__.py" (in directory
"C:\Users\Steve\PycharmProjects\lmageProcessing\src"):
 CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Answer (score 26):

Today i Also face this problem although @alecxe answer is good for one project settings

If you want to set flake8 globally , you can follow below process

1. make sure flake8 installed in your project
2. make sure virtualenv path set in pycharm
3. configure flake8 as external tool
   goto file> settings> (Tools) > External Tools > '+'

configure the path
[image]

Program -
The path to the flake8 executable **$PyInterpreterDirectory$** is a directory where the Python interpreter of the current project is placed

Argument- Specifies what files and folders should be checked **$FilePath$**

Working directory - Project root directory **$ContentRoot$**

Comment: To add a Keyboard Shortcut go to: Settings -> Keymap -> External Tools -> Flake8
Do a right click on Flake8 and select `Add Keyboard Shortcut` and select e.g. `Alt+F`

Answer (score 7):

To all the folks, who need:

- run against files using a **remote python interpreter with SSH**
- who want **only** flake8 on **changed files regarding git status**
- who want to **pass any other flake8 arguments** without pain

To setup that kind of tool in Pycharm:

```
File | Settings | Tools | Remote SSH External Tools
```

see below screen for example configuration:
[image]

Arguments: **`-c "flake8 $(git status -s | grep -E '\.py$' | cut -c 4-) --max-line-lengt=120"`**

In my case the crucial thing was:

1. use `/bin/bash` instead of `flake8` directly
2. Filling the arguments section by `-c "whatever args subcommands etc I need here"`

For reference:

- **`$(git status -s | grep -E '\.py$' | cut -c 4-)`** is responsible for passing locations of files with changes according to git version control
- https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000610520-Remote-SSH-external-tool-run-multiple-commands-once

**NOTE:** to have your flake8 from virtualenv you might want to specify full path like:
**`/z/your_virtual_envs/bin/flake8`**

Answer (score 5):

I've wrote a library that offer - kind of native flake8 integration with pycharm. The library work by pretending to be a pylint executable. It accept pylint arguments and translate it to flake8 counterpart. Similarly it translate flake8 output to equivalent pylint output.

Result is native flake8 support.

https://gitlab.com/ramast/flake8-for-pycharm/

Comment: Pretty much impossible. I am not a java developer so I can't make changes to existing plugins or create a new one.

This library i wrote was written in python and it depend on pylint plugin for it to work. There is no way such script can be accepted into market place

Answer (score 4):

Here's the approach I used, we basically need to tell flake8 how to output it's errors and tell pycharm how to interpret them. And then run the job when a file changes.

- Install the 'File Watcher' plugin if not already
- Click '+' under 'Tools' > 'File Watcher'
- Create something that looks like the following. We're basically telling flake8 how to format it's output and how pycharm should interpret it here (see [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-file-watchers.html#enableFileWatcher) and [this](https://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/user/options.html?highlight=--config#cmdoption-flake8-format))
  [image: screenshot]
- `flake8` (this assumes it's installed globally)
- `--format="ERROR: %(path)s[%(row)d, %(col)d]: %(text)s (%(code)s)" $FilePath$`
- `$FilePath$`
- `ERROR: $FILE_PATH$\[$LINE$, $COLUMN$\]: $MESSAGE$`

4. Now under 'Editor' > 'Inspections' make sure 'File Watcher Problems' is enabled

Comment: This worked perfectly for me on Windows 11 and PyCharm 2022.2.1 (Community Edition). Only a minor change: I used ```$ContentRoot$``` in the Working Directory field, instead of ```$FilePath$```

Comment: Very good guide about this approach (in Russian, but Google Translate is your friend): https://tirinox.ru/flake8-pycharm/