# Flake8 links in PyCharm are incorrect and do not take you to the source code

Tags: python, pycharm, flake8

I have setup my PyCharm as described in [Descriptive flake8 errors in PyCharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48066322/descriptive-flake8-errors-in-pycharm)
. The argument line looks like the following.

```
$FilePath$ --format='%(path)s:%(row)d,%(col)d:%(code)s:%(text)s:https://lintlyci.github.io/Flake8Rules/rules/%(code)s.html'
```

When I run Flake8 in PyCharm, I get the nicely formated text as described.

`'C:\Users\XYZ\PycharmProjects\TestProject\test.py:77,80:E501:line too long (106 > 79 characters):https://lintlyci.github.io/Flake8Rules/rules/E501.html'`

However, when I click on the error to goto the spot on the code, the link is invalid. For example, the links for above looks like the following.

`C:\Users\XYZ\PycharmProjects\TestProject\test.py:77,80:E501:line`

If I run the above from the terminal from within PyCharm I get the following output and the links work.

`test.py:77,80:E501:line too long (106 > 79 characters):https://lintlyci.github.io/Flake8Rules/rules/E501.html`

Any idea on why this is happening?

Answer (score 2):

For correct output you have to run flake8 command from working directory (project root)

Comment: True, but it's a bummer because my config file lives within my backend directory...

Comment: Ok, I went with a custom script with `--config backend/setup.cfg`

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the argument. The settings should be as follows.
Arguments:
`$FileName$ --format='%(path)s:%(row)d,%(col)d:%(code)s:%(text)s:https://lintlyci.github.io/Flake8Rules/rules/%(code)s.html'`

Working Directory:
`$ContentRoot$`